# How to show that this subgroup is normal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$H = \left\{ id, (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)\right\}$ is a subgroup of $A_4$.  A normal subgroup is a subgroup where the right and left cosets are the same.  To show that $H$ is a normal subgroup would I have to compute every single coset and show that the left and right cosets are the same?  Is there a clever way to do this problem?

Comment: I don't think $H$ is a subgroup of $A_4$, since $|H| = 7$, $|A_4| = 12$, but $7$ does not divide $12$, contradicting Lagrange's theorem. Maybe you put some extra element there. If were $|H| = 6$ instead of $7$, then $H$ would have index $12/6 = 2$, and every subgroup with index $2$ is automatically normal.

Comment: Woops, I incorrectly typed the subgroup.  I have fixed it in the edit.